# How to read from a binary file and load the data into a 3d vector in C++?

Tags: c++, vector, binaryfiles, istream, istream-iterator

I currently have some `.bin` files, each of which contains a matrix of size `AxBxC`. I would like to load it into a 3d vector `vector<vector<vector<float>>>` in C++, but encountered some problems.

I tried to flatten the matrix and load it into a buffer first, but the size of the buffer was weird so I got stuck there.

My code was:

```
vector<vector<vector<float>>> load_3d_bin(const std::string& path){
    vector<vector<vector<float>>> r;
    std::ifstream binary_feat(path.c_str(),std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<float> flattened_feat((std::istream_iterator<char>(binary_feat)),std::istream_iterator<char>());
    for(auto i: flattened_feat){
        int value = i;
    }
    std::cout<<flattened_feat.size()<<endl;

// code to be written

   return r;
}
```

Ideally `r` would be a 3d vector, but I am stuck at the iterator part as the `.size()` outputs differently from `total length = AxBxC`, which was what I expected...

Any solution or feedback? Thanks in advance!

--Edit:

Sorry for not being clear enough!
In my original `.bin` files, the floats are encoded as 3d matrices, i.e., in each file they are in an array of `AxBxC` size. I would like to first flatten the original 3d matrices and then reshape the flattened vectors into 3d vectors of size 'AxBxC'.

I managed to do the flattening part myself as follows:

```
typedef vector<vector<vector<float>>> t_f
typedef vector<vector<float>> m_f

t_f load_3d_bin(const std::string& path){
    t_f r;
    std::ifstream binary_feat(path.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<float> flattened_feat;
    float tmp = 0;
    binary_feat.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tmp), sizeof(float));
    while(!binary_feat.eof()) {
        binary_feat.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tmp), sizeof(float));
        flattened_feat.push_back(tmp); 
    }
    std::cout<<"file size:::"<<flattened_feat.size()<< std::endl;

# the reshaping code to be written

return r;
}
```

And now with the flattened vector I have, I tried to reshape it into a 3d vector, which is the `# the reshaping code to be written` part above:

```
t_f r(A, m_f(B));
for (int i=0; i<A; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<B; j++){
        for (int k=0; k<C; k++){
            r[i][j][k] = flattened_feat[(i*B+j)*C+k];
        }
    }
}
```

But I got segmentation fault... Any idea why I got the error and how to solve it? Or is it better to directly load the 3d matrices in `.bin` files to 3d vectors?
Thanks!

Comment: How are your floats encoded in the files?

Comment: 3d arrays (array in the general sense) can be realized by using a 1d array (e.g. std::vector) and managing the 3d strides and indices yourself. This is IMHO a better way than a "real" 3d data structure. It is the method used by opencv, numpy and others. And in addition it makes reading a file rather trivial.

Comment: If you show us the `save_3d_bin` function we can help you.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The original 3d `.bin` files were written in python... simply `np.array(3dfeatures).astype(np.float32).tofile(3dbin_path)`, where `3dfeatures` is a 3d np array.

Comment: @Ziggy1209 Perhaps you should include the shortest possible python script that produces such a file in the question. It could give the those interested something to test on when trying to deserialize it in a different language.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your bin files just contain a flat concatenation of floats in binary format, in row-major order:

```
vector<vector<vector<float>>> load_3d_bin(const std::string& path){
  vector<vector<vector<float>>> ret(A, vector<vector<float>>(B));
  std::ifstream binary_feat(path.c_str(),std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);

  for (int i = 0; i < A; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < B; j++) {
      for (int k = 0; k < C; k++) {
        auto& row = ret[i][j].emplace_back(C);
        binary_feat.read(row.data(), row.size() * sizeof(float));
      }
    }
  }
  return ret;
}
```

Alternatively, you could use the fantastic [armadillo](https://arma.sourceforge.net/) library:

```
fcube c;
c.load(path.c_str(), raw_binary);
c.reshape(A, B, C);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the end I managed to do this myself.

The solution is as follows:

```
typedef vector<vector<vector<float>>> t_f
typedef vector<vector<float>> m_f
typedef vector<float> v_f

t_f load_3d_bin(const std::string& path){
    std::ifstream binary_feat(path.c_str(), std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    std::vector<float> flattened_feat;
    float tmp = 0;
    binary_feat.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tmp), sizeof(float));
    while(!binary_feat.eof()) {
        binary_feat.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&tmp), sizeof(float));
        flattened_feat.push_back(tmp); 
    }

    t_f r(A, m_f(B,v_f(C)));
    for (int i=0; i<A; i++){
        for (int j=0; j<B; j++){
            for (int k=0; k<C; k++){
                r[i][j][k] = flattened_feat[(i*B+j)*C+k];
            }
        }
    }

    return r;
}
```

The returned `r` is a 3d `vector<vector<vector<float>>>` of size `AxBxC`.

Comment: `while(!binary_feat.eof())` is wrong. You'll likely read one `float` too many that way. Why do you read and discard a `float` at the start? Just do `while(binary_feat.read(buf, sizeof(float))) { ... }`. It risky reading directly into the `float`. I'd recommend reading into a `char buf[sizezof(float)]` then `memcpy` the `buf` into the `float`.